# How to stop executing more similar requests at once

Tags: node.js, express, request

I'm making a simple server with node.js and express, but things break when somebody sends similar requests shortly after each other.

Here's an example:

```
app.post('/user/create', function (req, res) {
    if(req.session.loggedin){ 
        if(req.session.usertype == "Boss" || req.session.usertype == "Admin"){
            if(req.body.email.toLowerCase() == req.body.email_check.toLowerCase()){
                con.query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?", [req.body.email.toLowerCase()], function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if(result.length == 0){
                        if(req.body.link_teacher || req.body.type == "Učitel"){
                            con.query("SELECT * FROM ucitele WHERE inicialy = ? AND stale_uci = true", [req.body.initials.toUpperCase()], function (err, result) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                if(result.length == 0){
                                    var password = passgen.generate({
                                        length: 12,
                                        numbers: true,
                                        excludeSimilarCharacters: true
                                    });
                                    bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {
                                        con.query("INSERT INTO ucitele (inicialy, typ, stale_uci) VALUES (?, ?, true)", [req.body.initials.toUpperCase(), req.body.teacher_type], function (err, result) {
                                            if (err) throw err;
                                            con.query("SELECT id FROM ucitele WHERE inicialy = ? AND stale_uci = true", [req.body.initials.toUpperCase()], function (err, result) {
                                                if (err) throw err;
                                                if(result.length == 1){
                                                    con.query("INSERT INTO accounts (hash, email, type, id_ucitele) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [hash, req.body.email.toLowerCase(), req.body.type, result[0].id], function (err, result) {
                                                        if (err) throw err;
                                                        console.log("Added a teacher account with password: " + password + " email: " + req.body.email.toLowerCase() + " type: " + req.body.type);
                                                        res.status(201).redirect('/home?success=Registrace nového uživatele proběhla úspěšně.');
                                                    });  
                                                }else{
                                                    res.redirect('/register?error=Při vytváření účtu se stala chba, prosím kontaktujte správce.');
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });                                        
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    res.redirect('/register?error=Učitel s těmito iniciály už existuje.');
                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                            con.query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?", [req.body.email.toLowerCase()], function (err, result) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                if(result.length == 0){
                                    con
                                    var password = passgen.generate({
                                        length: 12,
                                        numbers: true,
                                        excludeSimilarCharacters: true
                                    });
                                    bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {
                                        con.query("INSERT INTO accounts (hash, email, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [hash, req.body.email.toLowerCase(), req.body.type], function (err, result) {
                                            if (err) throw err;
                                            console.log("Added an account with password: " + password + " email: " + req.body.email.toLowerCase() + " type: " + req.body.type);
                                            res.status(201).redirect('/home?success=Registrace nového uživatele proběhla úspěšně.');
                                        });
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    res.redirect('/register?error=Uživatel s tímto emailem už existuje.');
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        res.redirect('/register?error=Uživatel s tímto emailem už existuje.');
                    }
                });                
            } else {
                res.redirect('/register?error=Zadané emaily se neshodují.');
            }
        } else {
            res.status(401).redirect('/home?error=Na tuto akci nemáte dostatečná práva.');
        }
    } else {
        res.status(403).redirect('/login?error=Pro zobrazení této stránky se přihlašte.');
    }
});
```

When I post the same request to /user/create twice, until the first adds the email to the database, the second one has already checked if the email is duplicate and had enough time to execute up to the part where it INSERTS new row into the table "ucitele". So i end up with 2 new rows in one table and the server runs into error and crashes. I would like it to first fully execute the first request and then move onto the second one. In that case it would notice that this email is already in the database and not continue further. How could I achieve that (or improve my code to prevent the behiavor described)?

Comment: You should not and don't need to make request handling one by one instead you should make email unique in db and handle error properly and send client response of email already exists

Comment: This is an unrelated comment, but you should consider using an early termination pattern instead of nesting `if`s like this. Something like a series of `if (badCondition) return res.status(500);`.  It's difficult to read your code.

Comment: @zero298 I know it's difficult and it annoys me too, but how else am I supposed to tell the user where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should not and don't need to make request handling one by one instead you should make email unique in db and handle error properly and send client response of email already exists

Instead of throwing error

```
if(err){
    // send error response from here or call next(err) and handle err from error middleware
}
```

Error handling middle ware

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    //Handle error here
})
```

For duplicate entry 409 http status should be sent

And instead of using so many if's in route handler, you should use middleware for them like

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if(req.session.loggedin){
        next(); // will go to route handler
    }else{
        // You redirect code
    }
})
```

You need to put this before your route code, to understand more about middle ware follow this link - https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: The problem is the second request checks if the email exists before the first one adds it into the DB. Also, could you please elaborate on your sugggestions, I'm not really fluent in this environment yet. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I understand your issue, but it's not possible to make request handling one by one and if you made it possible any how it won't be a proper solution. What I want to say is, you're using MySQL DB so you can make email unique key in accounts table and then when second user's insert command executes it will give duplicate entry error, and in that case you should send Client error response

Comment: So it's not possible and the only workaround is to pass some check in the DB  queries?